# Remove non-existent AFP server from Finder sidebar?

Tags: finder, macos

For a while, I had a Linux-based AFP server in my network. Due to issues not related to this question, I've decided to switch it off. Problem is - the server still appears in the Finder sidebar. The original server name was `hostname-afp`, and for a few weeks, the entry of that name was still visible in the sidebar. About a week ago, the name changed to `hostname-2-afp`, now it is `hostname-3-afp`. Where does Finder store the reference to that server, and how do I remove it?

Unchecking the servers in the Finder preferences does not remove the server from the sidebar. Unchecking the Bonjour Computers does remove it, but I'd like to keep the Bonjour feature enabled, and re-checking Bonjour Computers makes the ghost entry reappear as well. Cmd-/Ctrl-/Whatever-Dragging the entry does nothing.

(El Capitan / 10.11.6)

Comment: @klanomath Bullseye - even after the removal of netatalk, there was a stray file /etc/avahi/services/afpd.service that was advertising the non-existent service. Please put that into an answer to collect the bounty :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably configured Avahi (a free zero-configuration networking implementation for Linux including multicast DNS/DNS-SD service discovery AKA **Bonjour**) manually to propagate the AFP-service running on your Linux server in the .local network.

Even after disabling the AFP service on the Linux server, the Linux server's Bonjour name will still be registered then and thus shown in the Mac's sidebar.

You can check this by entering `dns-sd -B _afpovertcp._tcp` in Terminal.app on the Mac.

So remove the manually created config file (here: */etc/avahi/services/afpd.service*) and restart the avahi service (probably `sudo service avahi-daemon restart`) to get rid of the non-existing AFP server name in the Mac's sidebar.

Comment: One minor point - Avahi automatically identifies when a service has been added/removed, so no need to restart it.

Comment: This worked great for my Terra-Master NAS (TNAS).